# Batch file to create new subfolder in directory and then copy all files from original folder to the new subfolder

Tags: batch-file

I have created a script which checks the folder names within a directory and creates a new one based the newest one. For example first time its run it will create sub folder named '1' next time its run it will create sub folder '2' and so on.

What I would like to do is also have a script which copies all the files in the original directory the first time its run into sub folder '1' and the next time its run into sub folder '2' and so on not quite sure how to achieve this.

My script below:

```
@echo off
set "Folder=C:\Users\Kearlvin\Documents\Development\CallRecordings\"
if not exist "%Folder%" (
    md "%Folder%"
    goto EndBatch
)
set "FolderCount=0"
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /AD /B "%Folder%*"') do set /A FolderCount+=1
md "%Folder%%FolderCount%"
set "FolderCount="
:EndBatch
set "Folder="
```

Comment: Your code already gets the what the newest directory is, so I am not sure what problem you are having with copying.